# JPanel identifier expected even with JPanel already declared

Tags: java, compiler-errors, identifier

I'm trying to add to a `JPanel` and it seems to be seeing it as a variable. I'm not sure how to fix it. I need it to display a music player style layout but this error seems to be appearing every time I try a `.add` method the error seems to be in the `panel.add(title)` or the way I'm declaring the panel but I'm not sure.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class MusicFrame extends JFrame
{
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();

    JLabel title = new JLabel("Song.mp3");

    panel.add(title);
}
```

Comment: What's the actual error?

Comment: @cwittah <identifier> expected panel.add(title);